# Jenkins won't start 2.375 with Unrecognized option: --handlerCountMax=100

Tags: jenkins

After updating Jenkins from 2.364 to 2.375 it fails to start. The error printed is:

```
Exception in thread "main" Unrecognized option: --handlerCountMax=100: Unrecognized option: --handlerCountMax=100
        at winstone.cmdline.CmdLineParser.parse(CmdLineParser.java:52)
        at winstone.Launcher.getArgsFromCommandLine(Launcher.java:399)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at executable.Main.main(Main.java:355)
```

Reverted back to 2.364 for now.

Comment: That's correct. If you read the [Change Log](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.375), you'd see they were removed and why.

Comment: @ian-w That's not helpful though.  The answer below helps solve the issue

Comment: @Max-de-graaf, it [literally says that](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.375): "_Align the default value of the HTTP keep-alive timeout in Winstone with that of the upstream Jetty project by changing it from 5 seconds to 30 seconds. Remove unused --ajp13Port, --ajp13ListenAddress, --handlerCountMax, and --handlerCountMaxIdle options. (issue 69509, Align HTTP keep-alive with Jetty default)_". The response below says "comment out or remove:". If the calling options have been removed, then you need to remove them from your wrapper. Exactly that

Comment: Also, [Linux installation packages migrated from System V init to systemd](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/03/25/systemd-migration/#content-top), so **init.d** is obsolete. And there's plenty of people who make the mistake of installing via package manager then upgrading the war by copying newer file, which is [the wrong approach and and causes problems](https://community.jenkins.io/t/jenkins-upgrade-issue-in-centos-7-inc/3884/5). use the package manager to update Jenkins and it migrates these settings for you.

Answer (score 18):

We were able to fix this issue by commenting out these specific parameters in the `init.d` Jenkins startup script. After that the Jenkins service was able to start up again.

Look for `PARAMS` in the script (`/etc/init.d/jenkins`) and comment out or remove:

```
[ -n "$JENKINS_HANDLER_MAX" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --handlerCountMax=$JENKINS_HANDLER_MAX"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HANDLER_IDLE" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --handlerCountMaxIdle=$JENKINS_HANDLER_IDLE"
```

Another fix might be to remove these configuration options in the Jenkins config file `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`. Look for `JENKINS_HANDLER_MAX` and `JENKINS_HANDLER_IDLE` and comment out or remove these options.

Comment: Best option is the last suggestion to remove the configuration options.  That should be the preferred answer

Comment: In my (maybe weird?) setup I had to remove the ajp13Port option from `/etc/default/jenkins` and `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf`